# CondaValueError: could not parse 'ÿþn a m e : m a t l a b _ 2 0 2 0 a ' in: .\environment.yml

Tags: python, conda, environment

Ideally I want a command that I can execute from a batch on Windows10. For the time being I'm experimenting with commands.

Right now this runs from a bat file but when I create an env from it the pip installs are not included.

```
:: Get the Anaconda Shell
call C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3

:: Switch environments
call conda activate matlab_2020a

:: Create env list
call conda list --explicit > C:\TortoiseSVN\xxxxxx\matlab_2020a-env.txt
```

So I tried this:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

The resulting file is not formatted correctly and leads to the error in the title:

> CondaValueError: could not parse 'ÿþn a m e :   m a t l a b _ 2 0 2 0 a ' in: .\environment.yml

What you may notice are a couple of characters that look like a y and b. After that there is space between every character in the file. Just glancing at the file in Atom leads me to think that the env includes the conda and pip installs. In other words, it has the correct content but it isn't formatted properly.

I'm less concerned with fixing the environment.yml file than I am creating a set of bat file commands that create env file which includes the pip installs and works for creating an environment. But I am curious if I'm missing a switch of something that would fix the environment.yml creation.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the output of `conda env export` is in UTF-16 format. Why that happens is above me.